# How can I update an object without replacing it in Supabase?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I have a function, `updateHistory`:

```
export const updateHistory = async (id, historyObj) => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("property")
    .update({ history: historyObj })
    .eq("id", id);

  return data;
};
```

I am calling it like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let tempHistory = {
      column: column,
      field: name,
      previousValue: `${defaultValue}`,
      updatedValue: `${changedValue}`,
      time: new Date().toISOString(),
    };
    let newHistory = [tempHistory, ...history];
    setHistory(newHistory);
    updateHistory(propertyId, newHistory);
  }, [changedValue]);
```

The goal is to have a log history with all previous values, with the current value being the 1st element in the array of objects. The issue is, with this code, it is just replacing the data in the history column with only the current value, rather than just adding to it and keeping the previous values.

I'm not sure why my current code is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a traditional database this is achieved by an additional insert operation (into the audit log). Unless Supabase has a built in auditing feature, I imagine you need a seperate insert operation

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The issue is, the history needs to be distinct per row, and inserting would create new rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. This is not an issue with Supabase. `history` was null at some points, which replaced the previous values of it with nothing.